# jQuery Modal dialog from URL, not using .load({modal:true})

Tags: jquery, url, dialog, include, modal-dialog

Quick: Suggestions please to the best way to load a URL in a modal dialog where the URL to be loaded is not imported into a DIV of the calling page.

More detail: I have an HTML page with a jQuery datatable in it.  When double clicking on a row, I want to load a modal dialog from a URL.  I usually use the jQuery UI dialog for my dialog windows.  The solution I've seen to this is to add a DIV to my page, say `<div id="divPopup">`, and then on dblclick load the dialog like this: $("#divPopup").load("my_url.html").dialog({modal:true});

This presents some problems in my case - essentially it is importing the page directly into the DIV, and some javascript includes are erring out - spec., one to Google location services.  The jQuery documentation refers to the same origin policy w.r.t. Ajax load calls.  Yes, I could include the Google location link in the parent page, but I don't like this idea from a design point of view, and it makes the dialog not-usable on a stand alone basis.  There are other problems - the loading page is complicated enough without importing more HTML/scripting  into it, and from a design point of view the dialog may need to include certain javascript files that the parent page has already included, etc.

I'd rather just load the window as a new modal window that isn't imported into the page.  I'm relatively new to jQuery.  Previously I used modal HTML dialog boxes but I'm not sure they are the best solution / cross browser friendly.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the needed div to be in an iframe.